# list opened ports, close port and open port under centos

Tags: linux, centos, port

I need to build a bash script to do the following:

- list opened ports
- close opened port
- open port under

What is the plan, packages and configuration to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nmap to get the list of host open/close ports

nmap --top-ports 20 hostname

```
e.g
nmap --top-ports 20 localhost
```

[image]

Comment: How can i close a port?
or open port?

Comment: First you need to identify the service corresponding to the port. For closing that particular port you may need to kill that service. I am giving the example , Please get formatted by copy the content:  [root ~]# nc -l 9999 & ;
[1] 7745
[root ~]# netstat -na|grep 9999;
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

[root ~]# ps -ef|grep -v 9999;
root      7745  7101  0 15:42 pts/0    00:00:00 nc -l 9999
[root ~]# kill -9 7745;
[1]+  Killed                  nc -l 9999
[root ~]# netstat -na|grep 9999;
no port listen

Comment: using this :

nmap -sT -O localhost